# Executing External Programs in pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal, launching-application

I want to open a program with below code but I can't

```
program launchprogram;
uses 
  Classes, SysUtils, Process;
var 
  AProcess: TProcess;
begin
  AProcess := TProcess.Create(nil);
  AProcess.Executable:= 'C:\Program Files (x86)\oCam\oCam.exe';
  AProcess.Parameters.Add('-h');
  AProcess.Options := AProcess.Options + [poWaitOnExit];
  AProcess.Execute;
  AProcess.Free;
end.
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please tell us more about "_but I can't_" and also about "_this problem_". Be more outspoken! ;o) At the first glance all correct. The program works fine at least for `AProcess.Executable:= 'regedit'; AProcess.Parameters.Add('/?');`

Comment: Are you sure your Executable string is correct?

Comment: This is a very poorly written question. What does `oCam.exe` do? What results were you expecting and exactly what did you observe?

Comment: I assume that oCam.exe is supposed to show a few lines of help. OCam is a screen capture tool, like e.g. Camtasia.

Comment: Then maybe requirement for  elevation causes problems.

Answer (score 0):

See: http://wiki.freepascal.org/Executing_External_Programs

I tried this on a linux machine and it works fine

```
SysUtils.ExecuteProcess(UTF8ToSys('/full/path/to/binary'), '', []);
```

or better:

```
SysUtils.ExecuteProcess(UTF8ToAnsi('/full/path/to/binary'), '', []);
```

It is also supposed to work in MSWin

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the use of TProcess on a linux machine:
`enter code here`

```
    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    VAR AProcess : TProcess;
    begin
     AProcess:= TProcess.Create(nil);
     Aprocess.Executable:= '/usr/bin/mysqldump';
     Aprocess.Parameters.Add('--user=root');
     Aprocess.Parameters.Add('--password=any');
     Aprocess.Parameters.Add('--result-file=/home/user/mydump.sql;
     Aprocess.Parameters.Add('database1);
     AProcess.Options := AProcess.Options + [poWaitOnExit,poUsePipes];
     AProcess.Execute;
     AProcess.Free;
     end;
```

hope this will help you. I think the executable is not wright